# Any better function to generate a random integer?

Tags: javascript, math, random

I wrote a function:

```
function rand(minDit, maxDit){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxDit - minDit + 1)) + minDit; 
}
```

I use it to generate a random integer from minDit to maxDit, I want to know if there is a better solution ?

Comment: @Jimco: anything wrong with your code? Does it solve the issue it should solve? Any **real technical reason** to search for "the better" solution?

Comment: @venkateshwar: `0` is a valid value in this case.

Comment: @venkateshwar: what "same" problem? ;-) I don't see any problems explanation in the question.

Comment: zerkms— the +1 is required if the range includes the maximum value and `Math.floor` is being used. Using round will include the minimum and maximum values but at a lower probability than all other numbers in the range (roughly half since they will only occur for round down or round up respectively, whereas others will occur for rounding up and down).

Comment: @RobG: yep, now I see the difference, thanks

Comment: @zerkms—the initial number is (roughly) evenly distributed in the range but round affects that. e.g. you'll get zero for values from 0 to 0.49999999, but you'll get 1 for values from 0.5 to 1.49999999, which is twice the range. Same for the max value.

Comment: @RobG: yep, I got it right after my initial comment revision. That's why I edited it after ;-)

Comment: `i=new Date%100` instead of `i=0|Math.random()*100` is NOT a good idea in case someone is considering that possibilit[y](https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques)

Comment: I was playing with [this code](http://jsbin.com/edajal/5/edit) in a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523180/a-random-number-between-1-and-4-thats-not-another-random-number/12523496#12523496). It may be what you need.

Comment: @elcanrs The code you reference is not guarenteed to complete it is just highly likely to. It also is extremely inefficient for narrow ranges of relatively high numbers, say random numbers from 2^50 - 2^51.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Example.3A_Using_Math.random

Comment: @FelixKling You should make that the answer (after putting words around it so SO accepts it).

Comment: @chuckj: Yeah I know won't be good for huge numbers, it's not meant for that... but how would you make it work with large numbers faster?

Comment: @elclanrs Use the rand() presented in this (edited) question. However, the use of  indexOf() means ranges that are the equal or nearly equal to the range size will take a very long time. Your code only performs well on small ranges of random numbers where there array produced is significanly smaller than the range (or trivially short).

Comment: @chuck Would it be a good idea to then recursively call the function in chunks of let's say 10000 and then join the results? It wouldn't be completely random for ranges of 10000 or more tho...

Comment: @elclanrs I feel we have strayed too far from the original question. Feel free to e-mail me directly if you want to continue discussing this.

Comment: Don't worry about it I'm just playing with this code. I might hit you up if I find a solution. xD